# Unity3d www.progress not working in iOS

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, unity-game-engine

I am posting values to web service and getting response from the same web service and i am

using **WWWForm** in **Unity3d**. Now i want to wait till the response not completely load . For that

i have use **`yield www;`** but it's not working properly. After that i found **`www.progress`** and

it's working in my **Unity3d** player but it is not working in iPhone or iPad.

**EDIT1 : I am using Javascript.**

EDIT2: My Code :

```
function getSettingsValues(){


    var strResponse;

    userID = PlayerPrefs.GetString("userid");
    arrLevels.Clear();

    print("First");
    var url = "http://WEBSERVICE";

    var form = new WWWForm();

    form.AddField( "userid",userID);

    var www = new WWW( url, form );

    yield www;

    if (www.error == null)
    {   
        strResponse = www.text;
    }


    print("Response "+strResponse); 
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code should look like this:

```
function PostMyForm()
{
    var form:WWWForm = new WWWForm();
    // todo: add form variables
    var www:WWW = new WWW(url, form);
    yield www;
    // todo: parse response
}
```

then call it with StartCorotuine.

```
StartCoroutine(PostMyForm());
```

or, if you are already in a co-routine:

```
yield StartCoroutine(PostMyForm());
```

Comment: i want to stop thread till the response in not load. do you now any alternate of this?

Comment: Co-routine is the best for this. Make sure you call StartCoroutine(YourPostMethod()) to make sure javascript is actually using a co-rotuine. Then it can be used to block you while you wait for it to complete (It will eventially complete or fail even if progress doesn't work).

Comment: can you explain it more?

Comment: Unity has co-rotuines for javascript documented here: http://docs.unity3d.com/Documentation/ScriptReference/MonoBehaviour.StartCoroutine.html

Comment: i have try it. No luck.

Comment: I'll add some code above for an example.

Comment: I have updated Question.Please check.

Comment: Looks good to me. Make sure you call it with StartCoroutine(getSettingsValues());

Comment: Finally issue solved. We have to use yield StartCoroutine("getSettingsValues"); instead of StartCoroutine("getSettingsValues");. Thanks :)

Comment: ahh, that means you were already in a co-rotuine. I'll ammend my answer,

Answer (score 0):

```
while (!www.isDone)
{
    yield return www;
}
```

you can try this code instead of directly return, progress is for downloading some assets, it only return 0 or 1 when you try to access a web service.

Comment: i am using javascript so above code will not work.